# Wordpress Redirect Issue

Tags: wordpress

I currently have the code below added to my functions.php in order to redirect the users when they visit my website. The user is only redirected if the value of 'update_racer_record' is set to 'YES'.

However, I am getting a 'too many redirects' issue because Wordpress keeps redirecting the user even after he has reached the final page. In order to stop this I added the 'is_page' condition, but that doesn't seem to be working. I'm still getting the 'too many redirects' error.

What am I missing?

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_redirect' );

function my_redirect(){

    global $wpdb;

    // if user is logged in
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {

      // set vars
      $racer_id = find_racer_id();
      $update_racer_record = 'NO';

      // check to see if the user record has been updated in the last 6 months
      $update_racer_record = $wpdb->get_var("
                select 'YES'
                  from flx_racers
                 where racer_id = " . $racer_id . "
                   and ifnull(update_date, date_sub(now(), interval 7 month)) < date_sub(now(), interval 6 month);
      ");

      // if user record has not been updated in the last 6 months, redirect
      if ( $update_racer_record == 'YES' ) {

        // if we are not currently already in the personal info page, then redirect to it
        if ( !is_page( 'flx-racer-personal-info' ) ) {
          wp_redirect( site_url().'/flx-racer-personal-info/' ); exit;
        }

      }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it and now it works perfectly! Simply by changing the add_action code…

From this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_redirect' );
```

To this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_redirect' );
```